# Cosa significa "al minimo dei giri" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Era stata Fulvia a imporgli di scriverle, al termine del
>   primo invito alla villa. L’aveva chiamato su perché le traducesse i versi di *Deep Purple*. Penso si tratti del sole
>   al tramonto, gli disse. Lui tradusse, dal disco **al minimo
>   dei giri**.

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "al minimo dei giri" nel brano precedente. Immagino che abbia qualcosa a che vedere con il disco in vinile, ma non riesco a cogliere il suo senso. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: il minimo dei giri (modulo l'unità di tempo che non ricordo, minuti?) con cui è possibile far girare un disco su un giradischi (pre rivoluzione digitale)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il riferimento sicuramente è rivolto ai dischi in vinile. "Al minimo dei giri" secondo me indica che per tradurre più agevolmente il brano in riproduzione, il soggetto di "tradusse" abbia preferito rallentare il disco.

Comment: Cos'è "il soggetto di tradusse"?

Comment: @Charo “Lui tradusse”. I giradischi hanno un selettore per andare a 33 giri al minuto o 45; probabilmente il disco in questione era un 45 giri.

Comment: Ah! Capisco: il soggetto del verbo "tradusse" nella frase.

Comment: Esattamente @Charo. Mi riferivo a Lui.